# dynamically add variables in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

i have a script that add educational record to my database. my point is that i want to add variable dynamically depending upon the values user add. following is the script and jsfiddle example to show.

```
$(function() {
     var inc =1;
    $('.add').live('click',function(){

    var $val1= $('.val1').val();
     var $val2= $('.val2').val();
        var $val3= $('.val3').val();
        var $val4= $('.val4').val();
       var result = $val1 + $val2 +$val3 +$val4;

        var hiddin="get_val"+inc;
            var edu="edu"+inc;
        var grade="grade"+inc;
        var grp="grp"+inc;
        var colg="colg"+inc;
        //alert(hiddin);
        $('<div class='+hiddin+' style="display:block;">'+'<span class='+edu+'>'+$val1+'</span>'+'<span class='+grade+'>'+$val2+'</span>'+'<span class='+grp+'>'+ $val3 +'</span>' +'<span class='+colg+'>' +$val4 +'</span>'+ '</div>').appendTo('.wrap');

        // alert(result);
     var $val1= $('.val1').val('');
     var $val2= $('.val2').val('');
        var $val3= $('.val3').val('');
        var $val4= $('.val4').val('');
     inc++;
    });


    $('.submit').live('click',function(){

         var $edu1= $('.edu1').html();
            var $edu2= $('.edu2').html();
                 var $edu3= $('.edu3').html();
                 var $edu4= $('.edu4').html();
        var $grade1= $('.grade1').html();
            var $grade2= $('.grade2').html();
                 var $grade3= $('.grade3').html();
                 var $grade4= $('.grade4').html();
        var $grp1= $('.grp1').html();
            var $grp2= $('.grp2').html();
                 var $grp3= $('.grp3').html();
                 var $grp4= $('.grp4').html();

        var $colg1= $('.colg1').html();
            var $colg2= $('.colg2').html();
                 var $colg3= $('.colg3').html();
                 var $colg4= $('.colg4').html();

        alert($edu4 + $colg3 + $grp2 + $grade3);
    });
});
```

following is the link http://jsfiddle.net/Apexusman/g7PSH/5/
please help

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated `.live` method and if you have something like `val1`, `val2`, ... you are usually doing things wrong. Also, why do you name those variables `$val1` etc? They don't even contain jQuery objects and even then this naming scheme is questionable.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve? The selected values of all your select element when you press submit. or do you want to populate the next select from the selected value of your previous select element. Your code is also quite messed up.
Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to set some hidden variables to span and get the value. something like this

```
 $('<div class='+hiddin+' style="display:block;">'+'<span class='+edu+'><input type="hidden" name="edu[]" id="edu_'+inc+'" value="'+$val1+'" >'+$val1+'</span>'+'<span class='+grade+'><input type="hidden" name="grade[]" id="grade_'+inc+'" value="'+$val2+'" >'+$val2+'</span>'+'<span class='+grp+'><input type="hidden" name="group[]" id="group_'+inc+'" value="'+$val3+'" >'+ $val3 +'</span>' +'<span class='+colg+'><input type="hidden" name="college[]" id="college_'+inc+'" value="'+$val4+'" >' +$val4 +'</span>'+ '</div>').appendTo('.wrap');
```

and change the html

```
  <form id="save_form">
    <div class="wrap"> </div>
  </form>
```

and get the values by using jquery serialize

```
var data_save = $("#save_form").serialize(); 
alert(data_save);
```